# Permutations in Python without repetitions

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I am working on a program that gets a list as input from user and supposed to print all the permutations of the list.
the thing is that the output I'm getting is with repetition of numbers from the list, So these are technically not really permutations. How can I avoid this?
(notice that if a user inputs the same number twice in the list, this won't count as repetition) so basically I can't repeat the same index in every combination.

NB: I'm not allowed to use built in `permutations` functions.

This is what i've done so far:

```
def permutation(numberList,array,place):
    if (place==len(numberList)):
        print array
    else:
        i=0
        while (i < len(numberList)):
            array.append(numberList[i])
            permutation(numberList,array,place+1)
            array.pop()
            i+=1

def scanList():
    numberList=[];
    number=input()
    #keep scanning for numbers for the list
    while(number!=0):
       numberList.append(number)
       number=input()
    return numberList


permutation(scanList(),[],0)
```

the output for `1 2 3 0` for example:

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 3]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 3]
[3, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 2]
[3, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 1]
[3, 3, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
```

thanks.

Comment: permute the indices not the numbers.

Comment: what does it mean? what can i change in the code to do that?

Comment: Add each permutation as a tuple to a set and check the set each time.

Comment: say your array has 3 elements. generate permutations of [0, 1, 2] (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python). Then for every permutation P print numberList[P[0], P[1], P[2]]. do you get it?

Comment: not really, sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to use a `set` to know which numbers you already used and which ones you didn't:

```
def permutation(numberList,array,visited,place):
    if (place==len(numberList)):
        print array
    else:
        i=0
        while (i < len(numberList)):
            if i not in visited:
                visited.add(i)
                array.append(numberList[i])
                permutation(numberList,array,visited,place+1)
                array.pop()
                visited.remove(i)
            i+=1

def scanList():
    numberList=[];
    number=input()
    #keep scanning for numbers for the list
    while(number!=0):
       numberList.append(number)
       number=input()
    return numberList


permutation(scanList(),[],set(), 0)
```